# How do I add the degree symbol and letters to each value along the x- and y-axis of a graph

Tags: r, geospatial

So I am trying to add the degree symbol and some letters to the axis values of my graph to make them look like longitude and latitudes.

My current graph:

[image]

Want to make the axis look like this graph (with e.g., 90°N etc.)

[image]

This is the code I am using to generate my current graph:

```
    image.plot(lon_baseline_temp, lat_baseline_temp, dat_baseline_temp, 
               col=rev(brewer.pal(11,"RdBu")), xlab="", 
               ylab="", 
               main="Global surface temperature (Baseline)", sub="Year 1970 ~ 1999", font.sub=2,
               legend.lab="K", legend.line=2.5, legend.mar=7, 
               xaxp=c(-180, 180, 6), yaxp=c(-90, 90, 6), las=1)

       title(ylab = expression(paste("Latitude  "(degree))), line = 2, cex.lab = 1)
        
       title(xlab = expression(paste("Longitude "(degree))), line = 2.5, cex.lab = 1)
        
       minor.tick(nx = 5, ny = 5, tick.ratio = 0.5)
        
       map(database = 'world', add = T, lwd=1.5)
```

I would really appreciate any help on this soon, thank you very much!

Comment: Could you export your data using `dput`? if it is extremely large, you could truncate it to `n` observations by `dput(head(df, n))`

Comment: I am sorry but I am not very sure what you mean by your comment, I am quite a novice in Rstudio.

Comment: Lets say your data frame is called `df`. If you type `dput(df)` it will give you the structure of the data that you can share in online forums such as this.

Comment: Hi, I have tried doing that and because I am using a very large dataset, its longitude and latitude points across the world, so I think 36000 data points, which is quite hard to show you. And because the data I am using is taken directly from my computer.

Comment: Hi yes as I mentioned you can specify the number of observations (`n`) to output by `dput(head(df, n))` which will give you the first `n` values, or `df[sample(nrow(df), n), ]` which will give you a random sample of `n` values.

Comment: Hi, this is what I got ```> dput(head(dat_baseline_temp, 1))
structure(c(226.834533691406, 227.97575378418, 232.665878295898, 
237.997283935547, 244.246566772461, 248.112747192383, 248.002624511719, 
244.030853271484, 242.706817626953, 242.894561767578, 244.697250366211, 
248.094131469727, 252.940475463867, 253.918716430664, 254.660614013672, .... .Dim = c(1L, 180L))```, I tried showing more but there is a word count for the comments, so I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I have managed to get what I want now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I cant use your data but I think you just need to use a specify your labels as follows:

```
#some example plot
g <- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(50,50)) + ylim(0,100) + xlim(0,100) + labs(y = "Latitude",x = "Longitude")
#plot it
g

#add a new scale with specific labels
g + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,25,50,75,100),
                       limits = c(0,100),
                       labels = c(expression(0~degree),
                                  expression(25~degree),
                                  expression(50~degree),
                                  expression(75~degree),
                                  expression(100~degree)
                                  )
                       ) +
  labs(y = "Latitude",x = "Longitude")
#plot
g
```

[image: output]

Comment: Hi, I have used part of your code, essentially adding ```+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-90,-60,-30,0,30,60,90), limits = c(-90,90),labels =(expression(-90~degree), expression(-60~degree), expression(-30~degree), expression(0~degree), expression(30~degree), expression(60~degree), expression(90~degree)))``` to the first part of my original code, the image.plot part. But I am getting returned with NULL, although it seems to run smoothly, giving me the original plot but nothing else different. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Hi, I have managed to get what I want now. Thank you for your help!